# Set a time limit for computations in Magma CAS

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

I'm new to Magma CAS and looking for a way to abort a computation if Magma exceeds a given time limit. I know that Singular CAS calls this [watchdog](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/latest/sing_951.htm#SEC1026), but I couldn't find something similar in the [Magma handbook](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/).

In case there is no way to abort arbitrary computations, it would be sufficient to set a time limit on Gröbner basis computations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAGMA does not support this feature in general. However for many command like, Computation of `LOG`, `HOM`, and a few others, it has internal timer. You can set to a positive real number, e.g. `TimeLimit = 10`.

One such example is [here](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/815).

For more general bound, I would suggest use system level timers. (Assuming you have linux or any other shell based system). e.g. on ubuntu you can use: `timeout` (`apt-get install timeout`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: `TimeLimit` doesn't seem to exist anymore. One magma alternative to `timeout` seems to be `Alarm(s)` described [here](https://conf.math.illinois.edu/Software/magma/text106.html).